# org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies while calling doUpdate() method

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

So I am trying to update my repository before committing my files using SVN Kit. So I update my repository `svnUpdateClient.doUpdate(file, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false);` . But when the doUpdate() method gets called I get the following error.
`org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies`. What should I do to not get this exception?

Here is minimal reproducible example.

```java
//Updates the repository
SVNUpdateClient svnUpdateClient = clientManager.getUpdateClient();
svnUpdateClient.doUpdate(files, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false);

//adds the non working copy to the repository
SVNWCClient wcClient = clientManager.getWCClient();
wcClient.doAdd(file, false, false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false);

//commits the added/modified copy to the repository
SVNCommitClient commitClient = clientManager.getCommitClient();
commitClient.doCommit(files, false, commitMessage, null, null, false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
```

Comment: Perhaps provide a path to the working copy which you want to update?

Comment: The whole parent path of the file instead of the file?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Actually I have cleared the exception. The mistake I did was trying to update the repository before adding the non working copies.